# How do I defeat Fuad the Cannibal?

Tags: diablo-iii

While exploring the Howling Plateau I encountered Fuad the Cannibal in his very small cellar.

I can get the fight going well but when he hits me he gets a massive healing bonus.

Is the strategy simply to deal massive damage and wipe him out or is there some trick to defeating him?

Comment: Usually you meet Vampiric mobs in an open space, but Fuads room is so small you are barely able to kite. The best bet is stunning and avoiding melee.

Comment: @Mikle Luckily Fuad is slow by nature, so any additional slowing skill will slow him enough to kite him inside the small room.

Comment: @Sjoerd I don't remember him being slow, but I only met him one time, so I'll take your word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just stunned him and hit him a few times then left the dungeon and repeated until he had no health! Health bars don't reset if you run away!

Comment: The problem is that if you don't land the stun he can end up right in the doorway and he'll hit you as you re-enter the dungeon... this works but I wanted a solution that doesn't game the area entry/exit.

Answer (score 2):

Fuad gets a health buff from his melee hits, so the trick is to stay away from him.  Use whatever abilities you have to kite him.

Comment: Can you define Kite him?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18903/10260

Answer (score 1):

The solution to defeating Fuad is indeed using a freezing/rooting/stunning attack to keep him rooted in place.

I'm running a Demon Hunter build, who was level 18 when I found Fuad, so avoiding melee has already become second nature.

Using Impale with Impact put some stun on my right mouse button.  To keep the high damage and to generate hatred I laid Hungering Arrow with Puncturing Arrow on the right button.

Caltrops with Torturous Ground worked very well to stop him when the Impale failed to ... if you're not level 18 Hooked Spines works fine as long as you're using reasonably fast weapons.

Vault with Action Shot lets you keep throwing arrows at Fuad while you're dodging his Melee attacks.

Evasive fire helps to add some movement away from Faud, but with how small his room is, this if EF fires off you're already in trouble.  Still it might save you from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

If your class has a blinding skill,you can step in,use it,lay down some damage,and then back out while the cooldown refreshes. Thats what I ended up doing because the monk is a straight melee class with very little in the way of ranged attacks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, he could have one of many monster buffs that elite monsters can get called **Vampric**, which leeches life from anything it attacks or any damage it deals.

I've had that problem where it took me a while to kill something like that because a monster had the vampric buff along with a frozen buff that everytime I got caught in the freeze, it healed the monster about half of his life. Also just make sure you are doing enough damage as well, check for upgrades to your weapon/primary stat before having another go at it. :)

And yes, just do as much damage as you can to him would be the primary trick to defeating him.

Answer (score 0):

your best be would be stun then attack and retreat when the stun no longer is in effect. try and use ranged skill along with that, but a simple battle would be if you are a wiz. use the frozen shock i believe it is then dish out some dmg while he is froze and the force wave skill equiped as well so once the freeze wears off shock him and stun him, i only have alevel 5 monk but i would asume use the skill to blind them and deal some dmg  while he's blinded, if you are a barb usehis shout to reduce dmg delt then use his stomp to stun him as well as his fisure skill to leave him in the continuous dmg, if you are a witch doctor DO NOT USE YOUR DOGS as they will give him life, just run around and use either jumping spiders or the queen spider, if you are a demon hunter, well just use your chain skill to slow him down the whole time and just kite him, i hope these ideas help you in your battle

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use any advice from this page and I killed him with my 37 DH on NM easily. Rapid fire constantly and used preparation when I ran out of hatred. Then when he ran up to me and tried striking me with his slow attack I'd just run to the other ehd of the room.

Answer (score 0):

If you play the witch doctor, you can kill him with help from your pets. Watch this inferno game play: