# I've encountered a mine that beckons you, can no longer find it

Tags: diablo-iii

I am in this part of the quest which is in Act 2 1st or 2nd part of the quest where there is a mine that beckons you to go in.

Before I go in, I heard a NPC lying on the ground moaning for help. He mention that there is something inside the mine. I cannot remember exactly what was the conversation but I remember that the enemy just give and eerie voice from inside the mine while im outside the desert.

As the enemy is too powerful for me (I was lvl 17 at that time) I came back later and could not find the mine. Has anyone encounter this? I talk to all my friends who has completed the game and search through the internet but no one saw it or mention about it.

Answer (score 2):

The game is littered with random "events" that only sometimes appear, so it's very possible that you have experienced an event your friends haven't.

When you leave and re-enter the game ("resume") the world map is randomly generated again, along with the random dungeons and events in it. So there's not much point "saving a dungeon for later" (unless you never leave).

Don't worry about it - there will be plenty of other events in the game. They are just there to spice out the gameplay, you don't lose anything by not doing them (except achievements), and with enough playthroughs you are quite certain to encounter it again.

Comment: I thought so for a moment but that was the only random dungeon which I unable to defeat. There is only one enemy in the mine as far as I can remember. So I thought it might be a unique dungeon? Why I said it was unique because it the only dungeon that someone 'speak' from outside.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer by searching all the random dungeon question.

Its call Faud's Cellar - FAUD THE CANNIBAL

A lot of people are having problem defeating and finding this dungeon:

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149617776

http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4209821476

[How do I defeat Fuad the Cannibal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68101/how-do-i-defeat-fuad-the-cannibal)

Comment: Fuad's Cellar does not have an NPC outside asking for help; only cultists looking make you into a sacrifice.

Comment: It isn't Faud. Faud is another dungeon altogether. This is a random gen event

Answer (score 1):

What you encountered was a mine taken over by cultists, in which the miner you encountered outside had released a monster (a dune dervish type monster if I recall correctly).

The inside area is very small and, in my opinion, quite unremarkable.

Comment: You are correct grimman. +1