# How do I run backwards whilst still attacking?

Tags: starcraft-2

In the video below, the presenter manages to turn his marines around, move them away, shoot back at the Zerglings and then continue moving:

How is this accomplished? Does he do this by right-clicking to move and then pressing the Attack command? (i.e. 'T', I'm using grid)

Comment: yes he does exactly that. Move away attack move then move away again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes he does. He is moving then issuing an attack move command on the same spot. This is called [Kiting your opponent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18903/28182). It's effective because you use the cooldown between attacks to move, effectively shooting at the same rate (if done perfectly) while still being able to move.

You can see it yourself in that video that he links. You just need to know that when there's that green arrow indicator that it means a move command (ie right click) was issued. Whereas if the indicator is red it means an attack move command was issued (ie 'T' left click on ground).

Ideally you want to attack move back towards the direction that the enemy is so that those units out of range will go back to attack as well.

Comment: The problem is: After I select units and do right-click, the units just move till that right click place and then only attacking.. In the video, if you observe, he is right-clicking somewhere and hez able to attack immediately too. how hez doing? When I right-click and click 'attack', they're not atacking, instead they're just moving to that right place first..

Comment: @JohnG right click so that they're moving to that place, then **As they're moving** click T and then **Left** click on the ground so that they shoot then right click on the ground so they keep moving again